# Problem Publishing NUnit Testing Result Reports with Hudson

Tags: nunit, hudson

I am facing a problem with Hudson and NUnit testing. When trying to publish the Test Result Report for NUnit, the option in Hudson, i.e., "Publish NUnit Test Result Reports", is creating a problem. I am unable to provide the Path of the already-created XML file under the workspace folder of the Job. When I set the path of my file, i.e., "nunit-result.xml" and run the job, it throws an error:

```
"No test report files were found. Configuration error?"
```

Can anyone please help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may just have the wrong path. Go to your job and click "Workspace" to explore the workspace and figure out where the file is being generated.

Comment: look in jobs/<job name>/builds/<run #> if the xml file exists

Comment: The TestResults.xml is generating at the NUnit folder for my project, but I still get the above error after giving the correct path... Is there any reason why???

Comment: If you're sure you specified the correct path, are you sure it's in the correct casing? For some reason this is an issue, even on Windows. I had a case where Testresult/TestResult.xml didn't work and TestResult/TestResult.xml did.

Answer (score 2):

Check the the beginning of the log where the clone is made. Sometimes when you have the "Enable concurrent builds" option it triggers another build in a different workspace called your-project-name@2/source and that's why it can't find the reports