# No test report files were found in Hudson with NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, hudson

I could successfully run `NUnit` in `Hudson` using batch command and it generates the `TestResult.xml` in the `NUnit` installation directory. But `Hudson` generates the error that

```
No NUnit test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

after the correct path is given to the xml file under `Publish NUnit test result report`. Should the xml file be in the project's workspace or is there any other configuration to make this work???

I referred to the [Problem Publishing NUnit Testing Result Reports with Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967048/problem-publishing-nunit-testing-result-reports-with-hudson)
too but no answer was found.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After trying in different ways to solve the above problem, I could solve it by placing the `TestResult.xml` file in the workspace folder for the project in `Hudson` s `jobs` folder and giving only `TestResult.xml` under `Publish NUnit test result report` instead of giving the absolute path to the xml file.

Hope this may help someone...

Comment: yes, you should be able to use the path relative to the workspace root. For example, project/tests/TestResult.xml, or if you have multiple results, project/tests/*.xml.  Note there is no leading /

Answer (score 0):

I found that using double quotes is not working.

Example:

Test report XMLs = nunit-result.xml             (works!)
Test report XMLs = "nunit-result.xml"             (do NOT work)

There is a SMALL chance that this is your problem...